# How do I filter questions -- for dummies?

Tags: support, new-users, filtering, user-interface

There have been similar questions before, but nothing completely basic like I (and presumably others) need.

I have some knowledge and would like to contribute, so I click on the big "Questions" button at the top of the screen.

I see a *bunch* of questions, most about topics I know nothing about.
[image]

I can filter the questions a little bit, by selecting the "newest," "featured," "frequent," etc buttons, but that's not very useful.  There are still so many in each category that are quite beyond my scope of knowledge.

Each question has tags.  I know, because I've asked a few.  It would be really nice to be able to filter the questions by tag.  But I can't see any place/way to do this.

For example: What button/sequence would I have to do to filter out all the questions except for the ones about ANDROID and LISTVIEW?

Seriously, I don't know where to start, and this seems like such an obviously useful part of SO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Click on a tag to view only question containing that tag. You can also combine tags with `and`  / `or` in the search box

```
[android] and [listview]
```

will list only questions containing both tags.

You can find out more about searching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Thanks.  Would've taken decades before I would have thought to try surrounding the tag-words in square brackets.  How in the world did you find that particular help page?

Comment: When you search something - on the right is a link to *advanced search*. When you click it you find that site link too.

Answer (score 1):

On the right side of the main page, there are "Favorite Tags" and "Ignored Tags".
You can edit and add new tags on both of them, then next time you click "Questions" button, you will see what you want to see and won't see what you don't want to see.