# Is it possible to view new questions based on the tags which interests me?

Tags: discussion, support

I am a relatively new user on StackOverflow. In questions tab, I can see the newest questions posted. Is it possible to filter out questions based on the tags which are of interest to me?

Comment: Use Favorite tag on the right of home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this - [Filtering questions based on my Favorite Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131810/filtering-questions-based-on-my-favorite-tags)

Your favorites get highlighted, the ignored ones get hidden.
[image]

There are two options that may be helpful:

**Tag Sets**

This page would provide with the feed of all questions based on your user fav tags. You may create your own tag sets.

Further reading: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/

**Custom URL's**-
[Filter questions by favorite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256394/filter-questions-by-favorite-tags)

For Filtering you can refer these:
[How do I filter questions -- for dummies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252377/how-do-i-filter-questions-for-dummies)
[Filtering questions by specifying multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/filtering-questions-by-specifying-multiple-tags)
[Filtering questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/filtering-questions-by-multiple-tags)